Count how many lines have and R or a Y and remove them
I genotyped samples from methylation reads.
I was surprised that many of the alternative alleles were degenerate bases: R or Y.
V00001.vcf
##FORMAT=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Read Depth">
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  NA00001
NW_022882922.1  28895   .       C       T       0       PASS    NS=1:DP=52      GT:GQ:DP        0/1:0:52
NW_022882922.1  36586   .       C       T,Y     0       PASS    NS=1:DP=23:GU=T/C       GT:GQ:DP        1/2:0:23
NW_022882922.1  36640   .       G       A       0       PASS    NS=1:DP=40      GT:GQ:DP        1/1:0:40
NW_022882922.1  39071   .       A       G       0       PASS    NS=1:DP=43      GT:GQ:DP        1/1:0:43
V0021
##FORMAT=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Read Depth">
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  NA00001
NW_022882922.1  25160   .       G       Y       0       PASS    NS=1:DP=34:GU=T/C       GT:GQ:DP        0/1:0:34
NW_022882922.1  25676   .       T       C       0       PASS    NS=1:DP=41      GT:GQ:DP        0/1:0:41
NW_022882922.1  28342   .       G       A,R     0       PASS    NS=1:DP=35:GU=A/G       GT:GQ:DP        1/2:0:35
NW_022882922.1  29887   .       C       A       0       PASS    NS=1:DP=48      GT:GQ:DP        0/1:0:48
One sample had way more degenerate bases:
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  NA00001
NW_022882922.1  8082    .   G   A   0   PASS    NS=1:DP=6   GT:GQ:DP    0/1:0:6
NW_022882922.1  11106   .   T   G   0   PASS    NS=1:DP=19  GT:GQ:DP    0/1:0:19
NW_022882922.1  17828   .   C   G   0   PASS    NS=1:DP=27  GT:GQ:DP    0/1:0:27
NW_022882922.1  25160   .   G   Y   0   PASS    NS=1:DP=37:GU=T/C   GT:GQ:DP    0/1:0:37
NW_022882922.1  27396   .   G   A,R 0   PASS    NS=1:DP=33:GU=A/G   GT:GQ:DP    1/2:0:33
NW_022882922.1  28342   .   G   A,R 0   PASS    NS=1:DP=27:GU=A/G   GT:GQ:DP    1/2:0:27
NW_022882922.1  28895   .   C   T   0   PASS    NS=1:DP=32  GT:GQ:DP    0/1:0:32
NW_022882922.1  29887   .   C   A   0   PASS    NS=1:DP=35  GT:GQ:DP    0/1:0:35
NW_022882922.1  40905   .   T   C,Y 0   PASS    NS=1:DP=17:GU=T/C   GT:GQ:DP    1/2:0:17
NW_022882922.1  43671   .   A   C   0   PASS    NS=1:DP=11  GT:GQ:DP    0/1:0:11
NW_022882922.1  43859   .   A   T   0   PASS    NS=1:DP=18  GT:GQ:DP    0/1:0:18
NW_022882922.1  46336   .   G   A,R 0   PASS    NS=1:DP=26:GU=A/G   GT:GQ:DP    1/2:0:26
When I try to combine them with GATK, I got an error because of them.
I have preprocessed my samples in two different ways.
My aims are:
first, count and estimate the percentage of degenerate sites (with R/Y). I can count how many total sites there are with bcftools but I don't know how to count degenerate sites.
Lastly, after knowing which preprocessing is better, I would like to filter those degenerate bases/sites to finally make my dataset.
Thanks;
I have tried filter with bcftools and vcftools but nothing for this is available.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. What you have asked may make sense to you but it is incomprehensible jargon full of random unexplained TLAs and ETLAs to most people here. You will have to explain what you mean and what you actually want to do to your data. Also add four spaces to the start of stuff which looks like if might perhaps be executable code of some sort.
